# Equilibrium of domain integral?

Tags: equilibrium

I'm reading [this paper](https://www.google.fi/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj0ucDHxsjOAhVMiCwKHYayASwQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cmap.polytechnique.fr%2F~jouve%2Fpapers%2Feuroef.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFz4Zu6tlpHK-1AEjVcRHNN4NuPKg&bvm=bv.129759880,d.bGg), p.2.,  on homogenization method in shape optimization where a model problem is given where there's a bounded reference domain $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^n$ ($n=2,3$). The domain is of linearly elastic material and it's successively submitted to $p$ surface loadings $\{f_i\}_{1<i<p}$ on its boundary $\partial \Omega$.

Then, for each set of forces, equilibrium of the domain is assumed, which is described by two integral equations:

$$\int_{\partial \Omega} f_i \cdot n \space ds = 0$$

and

$$\int_{\partial \Omega} f_i \cdot Q x \cdot n \space ds = 0 \space \forall i \in \{1,...,p\}$$

where $Q$ is a $N \times N$ symmetric matrix.

I would like to understand, why these integral equations (specifically why the first one does) describe the equilibrium condition?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about the interpretation of equations in an applied mathematics paper, it is not about a concept of physics.

Comment: @sammygerbil: since it refers to the equilibrium condition, I believe the question does involve physics.

Comment: @flippiefanus : Yes, the equilibrium of forces is legitimate physics. But this is asking what these 2 integrals are saying about the equilibrium of forces - ie the question is about the interpretation of mathematics, not the application of physics.